# Show that $2^q\equiv 1$ mod p

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $p=2q+1$ and $q$ be prime numbers, with $q\equiv 3\:(4)$. Show that $2^q\equiv 1\:(p)$.

So far I've tried to write $q$ as an expression of $p$ and I am assuming that I have to use little Fermat somehow, since $p$ is prime. But I can't figure out how to combine those two and I fail to see an alternative. I also don't see how to use the fact that $q\equiv 3\:(4)$.

I've also tried rewriting the equation to $2^q-1\equiv 0\:(p)$ from which I need to show that $p=2q+1|2^q-1$. But I also got stuck there.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Since $q\equiv 3\pmod{4}\implies p\equiv 7\pmod{8}$
- You have to show $2^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$
- Note that $\left(\frac{2}{p}\right)\equiv 2^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\pmod{p}$ is $1$ if $p\equiv \pm{1}\pmod{8}$ and $-1$ if $p\equiv \pm{3}\pmod{8}$. Here $\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)$ denotes the [Legendre Symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol) and i have used [Euler's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion) which says $\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)\equiv a^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\pmod{p}$.
- From Apostol's Analytic Number Theory Book [image: this proof]

Comment: Is there a way to prove this without the use of the Legendre Symbol? I understand what you did and what it means, just wondering if there's a way without it.

Comment: I have added the screen shot. Hope it helps :)